# Interactions and Rlang: Error: ! `class` must be a character vector, not a list

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

So, I keep getting an error when trying to plot Johnson-neyman plots with the `sim_slopes` function of the Interactions package.

```
library(interactions)
m <- lm(mpg ~ hp * wt, data = mtcars)
sim_slopes(m, pred = hp, modx = wt, jnplot = TRUE)
```

error:

```
Error:
! `class` must be a character vector, not a list.
Backtrace:
 1. interactions::sim_slopes(m, pred = hp, modx = wt, jnplot = TRUE)
 3. jtools:::summ.lm(...)
 4. jtools:::do_robust(model, robust, cluster, data, vcov)
 5. jtools::get_robust_se(...)
 6. jtools::stop_wrap(...)
 8. rlang (local) `<fn>`(class = <named list>)
```

Packages versions:

```
packageVersion('rlang')# [1] ‘1.0.6’ 
packageVersion('interactions') # ‘1.1.5' .
```

I tested a few alternatives (RStudio cloud and friends' computers) and it seems like it's a problem with my R. I suspect it's something related to `rlang` but cannot fix it (already tried a few things, no success).

Any ideas on how to fix that or what may be causing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show your `packageVersion('interactions')` or `packageVersion('rlang')`

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reproduce your error.  It is working fine for me

Comment: @akrun  `packageVersion('rlang')# [1] ‘1.0.6’ ` and `packageVersion('interactions') # ‘1.1.5' `.

Tried with RStudio cloud and got the same error:
https://imgur.com/u6Ess3H

Comment: I was trying on the R console, may be there  is some compatability with Rstudio cloud

Comment: Do you have an updated version of Rstudio cloud?

Comment: @akrun asked a few friends to run the same code in their R and it seems to work just fine (like the picture you previously posted). Might be a problem with my Rlang

Comment: @akrun what is your version of jtools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

After reinstalling and updating all the dependencies for both `jtools` and `rlang`, the code started to run normally.

I don't know exactly where things started to work, but it seems to have been an issue with the many packages related to either `jtools` or `rlang`